# python mysql connector query string syntax

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

I am new to python mysql connector and I am trying to get results for a query that will find the user_ids with p_id = 0 will go to product table find how many products are available in that city

```
import mysql.connector
con = mysql.connector.connect(user='user', password = 'pass', host = 'blah.com')

cursor1 = con.cursor(buffered = True)

query = ("SELECT l.user_id, count(u.prod_id)"
        "FROM db1.users as l INNER JOIN db2.product as u "
        "ON l.u_city = u.p_city"
        "WHERE l.p_id =0 GROUP BY l.user_id limit 10;" )
cursor1.execute(query)
```

the query is getting executed mysql but from python mysql connector i am getting the following error

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/mysql/connector/update_campus_user_profile_suset.py
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/mysql/connector/update_campus_user_profile_suset.py", line 12, in <module>
cursor1.execute(camp_zip)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 491, in execute
self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 683, in cmd_query
statement))

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 601, in _handle_result
raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'l.campus_id <2 GROUP BY l.user_id' at line 1

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
query ='''SELECT l.user_id, count(u.prod_id) FROM db1.users as l INNER JOIN db2.product as u ON l.u_city = u.p_city WHERE l.p_id =0 GROUP BY l.user_id limit 10'''
```

- always it is better to intialize ur query to a variable with ('''stmt''') and execute
- there is no need of using `;`

Comment: Thank you but I wanted to split it in multiple lines. :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're just missing some spaces at the end of each line. Try:

```
query = ("SELECT l.user_id, count(u.prod_id) "
        "FROM db1.users as l INNER JOIN db2.product as u "
        "ON l.u_city = u.p_city "
        "WHERE l.p_id = 0 GROUP BY l.user_id limit 10;" )
```

Sometimes it's more natural to use a multi-line string:

```
query = ("""
        SELECT l.user_id, count(u.prod_id)
        FROM db1.users as l INNER JOIN db2.product as u
        ON l.u_city = u.p_city
        WHERE l.p_id = 0 GROUP BY l.user_id limit 10
        """)
```